# elasticsearch and solr performance benchmark

Tags: solr, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I need to setup a search server and I am looking for benchmark results to see the maximum limits of Elasticsearch and Solr.
I am going to be dealing with TBs (say 100TB) of data.
I am looking for data on:

a) Maximum index size on a single machine.
b) Maximum queries per second.
c) Maximum index speed MBs per second.

Machine detail: AWS m3.xlarge instance -> 64-bit, 4vCPU, 13ECU, 15GB RAM

Comment: Depends on schema, analysis complexity, kind of queries, index source, etc. Too broad...

Comment: @MauricioScheffer, I understand the points that you are saying, but I want to know the maximum limits of ES and solr. There is a threshold of every system, I want to see what exactly are the threshold for these technologies. Or at least, the max known limits.

You can imagine the most complex schema and query that you have worked on and index source will most probably be MySQl or Hadoop.

Comment: there is no such thing as a "most complex schema". Post the most complex schema you can imagine and I'll come up with a more complex one. Post the most complex query you can think of and I'll come up with a more complex query. That's not how things work. But you can run benchmarks with lots of fixed variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391305/where-can-i-find-performance-benchmarks-for-apache-lucene-solr

Comment: Mauricio is right, you are not going to get any sensible answer to this question until you specify in pretty great detail what your schema is, what kind of queries you are going to run, etc. Even then, the answer is going to be highly application specific.